# Share video from web to play inside WhatsApp

Tags: html, youtube, meta-tags, whatsapp

when a url of youtube video is posted on whatsapp (any group or contact) whatsapp converts it to wam (returns web.whatsapp.com/wam with some parameters) the result is a video player.

How can I do this from any website or web aplication?
There is some special metadata to send to whatsapp?